# Java - Socket Programming / Blocked ports

Tags: java, sockets, port

I'm trying to do a simple example of a client that connects to any website using 8080 port and print the first input from server. But I can't even connect to the server.
Trcking the TCP's headers with Wireshark, I realized that the servers aren't answering.
I've already turn off my Firewall, Antivirus and set the forwardings ports in my router, but I still can't connect to the server.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class ProtocoloX {
    //private byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[]{(byte) 0xC6, 0x57, 0x54, (byte) 0x95, 0x5E, (byte) 0x9E, 0x6B, (byte) 0xC6, 0x55, 0x17, 0x55,0x52, (byte) 0x9E, 0x21};
    private Socket cliente;
    private final String HOST = "stackoverflow.com";
    private final int PORT = 8080;

    public boolean connect(){
        this.cliente = new Socket();
        System.out.println("-- Trying to connect: "+HOST+":"+PORT);
        InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT); 
        try {
            this.cliente.connect(socketAddress, 10000000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("-- CONNECTION PROBLEM ");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println("-- Connection successful");
        return true;
    }

    private void receive(){
        InputStream stream = null;  
        System.out.println("-- Reading data...");
        try {
            stream = this.cliente.getInputStream();
            try {
                int count = stream.read(this.bytes);
                System.out.println("count:"+count);
                System.out.println("bytes:"+this.bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("-- DATA READING PROBLEM");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("-- DATA READING PROBLEM");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("-- Data read successful");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        ProtocoloX protocolo = new ProtocoloX();
        if(protocolo.connect()){
            protocolo.receive();
        }

    }
}
```

What could be causing the problem?
Thanks :D

Comment: `stackoverflow.com` is not listening on port 8080

Comment: the HTTP port is port 80.  8080 is the alternative HTTP port

Comment: Ok, now it's working to stackoverflow.com, but when I try any other website it throws me a read timeout exception. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get anything on port 8080 instead try on '80'. 80 is the default http port where internet websites listen for requests.

Comment: Ok, now it's working to stackoverflow.com, but when I try any other website it throws me a read timeout exception. What could it be?

Comment: @PauloRicardoXavierGiusti You have opened a raw socket. Before you read anything from the server, you need to send a http GET request. You are getting a timeout exception since you haven't send any request to the server yet and trying to read response. If you want a high level api that allows sending http requests then have a look at         [apache commons http library](http://hc.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Many WAN websites will not respond to an explicitly specified port query. For example, visiting http://www.stackoverflow.com:8080 in a web broswer will not get a response either. Verify that the server you are connecting to will accept connections on the 8080 port.

Comment: Ok, now it's working to stackoverflow.com, but when I try any other website it throws me a read timeout exception. What could it be?

Comment: Instead of using port 8080, I'm now using 80

Comment: It would help if you told me which server specifically you're trying to connect. There's a number of reasons why a connection could fail, and apparently StackOverflow isn't what you're really trying to connect to, so which server do you ultimately intend on connecting to? Is it even a public website?